# Why can't I get this combination of Math.random() and if/else statements to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the JQuery method, `.html`, to put `<img src='file.png'>` in a `<td>` based on the value generated by the `Math.random()` function. The if/else statements are used to determine the `td` in which `<img src='file.png'>` is added.

The problem is that, whenever I reload the page, `<img src='file.png'>` is always added to `#bottom-right` no matter what value is generated by `Math.random`.

Here's my code:

```
// script.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = Math.random;
    if (value <= 0.1) {
        $("#top-left").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.2 && value > 0.1) {
        $("#top-middle").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.3 && value > 0.2) {
        $("#top-right").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.4 && value > 0.3) {
        $("#middle-left").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.5 && value > 0.4) {
        $("#middle-middle").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.6 && value > 0.5) {
        $("#middle-right").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.7 && value > 0.6) {
        $("#bottom-left").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else if (value <= 0.8 && value > 0.7) {
        $("#bottom-middle").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    } else {
        $("#bottom-right").html("<img src='file.png'>");
    }
});

<!-- page.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td class="square" id="top-left"></td>
                <td class="square" id="top-middle"></td>
                <td class="square" id="top-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="square" id="middle-left"></td>
                <td class="square" id="middle-middle"></td>
                <td class="square" id="middle-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="square" id="bottom-left"></td>
                <td class="square" id="bottom-middle"></td>
                <td class="square" id="bottom-right"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: `Math.random` is a function and needs to be called `var value = Math.random();`

Comment: Learn to debug with console.log.  `var value = Math.random; console.log(value);` Also your if statements are more complicated than they need to be

Comment: @epascarello, how can I simplify my if statements?

Comment: There is no need to check the previous value since it already would have gone into its if. `if (x<=.1) {} else if(x<=.2) else if (x<=.3)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

```
var value = Math.random;
```

To :

```
var value = Math.random();
```

Comment: Especially amusing since the OP included the () in the title but not in his code. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
Math.random
```

change it to

```
Math.random()
```

otherwise value is just a function reference, which will always hit your else statement

Answer (score -1):

You also may need to round down the number to a single decimal place